# Separating items into ordered and unordered lists

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-2+

I'm trying to group all the types which have ordered-list-item & unordered-list-item into new object.

How can I simplify the function and reduce multiple return statements?

```js
const data = {
  data: [{
    areas: [{
        sections: [{
          rjf: [{
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "A title",
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "A title",
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        sections: [{
          rjf: [{
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "Block 2 A title",
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Block 2 Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Block 2 Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              "type": "heading-1",
              "text": "Block 2 A title",
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

function parseAreas() {
  data[0].areas.forEach(area => {
    this.moveToNewObject(area);
  })
}


function moveToNewObject(data) {
  const areas = data[0].areas;
  //console.log(data[0].areas)
  const listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'];
  return areas.map((area) => {
    var sec = area.sections;
    return sec.map((section) => {
      let lastHeadingIndex = -1;
      return section.rjf.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
        if (!current.type || !listItemTypes.includes(current.type)) {
          lastHeadingIndex = acc.length;
          return [...acc, current]
        } else {
          let listObject = acc.find((el, i) => i > lastHeadingIndex && i < index && el.type === 'list');
          if (!listObject) {
            listObject = {
              type: 'list',
              items: [current]
            }
            return [...acc, listObject];
          }
          listObject.items = [...listObject.items, current];
          return acc;
        }
      }, [])
    });
  });
}
console.log('sections', moveToNewObject(data.data));
```

Comment: an you give an example of what you expect the output to be? It's not clear from the description what the expected behavour is.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I simplify the function and reduce multiple return statements?

You *could* reduce the number of `return` statements by building up the new object in a more imperative way, without using the `map` and `reduce` functions,
but I'm not sure that would be better.
I think it's fine using functions as it is.

This part doesn't look great:

> ```
>   let listObject = acc.find((el, i) => i > lastHeadingIndex && i < index && el.type === 'list');
> ```

The problem with it is that you are using `lastHeadingIndex` to find the last heading added in `acc`,
but `acc.find` will search from the beginning.
With a large `data`, that would be a waste,
instead of searching from the end.

In fact, I'm wondering if `lastHeadingIndex` is important at all.
Isn't your real intention more like *"consecutive items of list type should be combined into a list object"*?
If that's the case, then you don't need to search from the end,
it's enough to look at the last item of `acc`:
if it's a list type, then append to it, if not, then create a new list type.

If this is indeed your real intention,
then you could get rid of `lastHeadingIndex`, and write a bit simpler:

```
function moveToNewObject(data) {
  const listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'];
  return data[0].areas.map(area => {
    var sec = area.sections;
    return sec.map(section => {
      return section.rjf.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
        if (!listItemTypes.includes(current.type)) {
          acc.push(current);
          return acc;
        }

        if (!acc.length || acc[acc.length - 1].type !== 'list') {
          acc.push({type: 'list', items: [current]});
          return acc;
        }

        acc[acc.length - 1].items.push(current);
        return acc;
      }, [])
    });
  });
}
```

I would also change the name of the function,
because `moveToNewObject` sounds overly generic,
it doesn't seem to describe its real purpose.
How about `combineListItemTypes`,
or `transformCombiningListItemTypes`?